# How can I access a particular table inside another table in JSON file by typing in localhost?

Tags: json, angular, rest

Typing `localhost:3000` got me this full json file.

```json
{
  "dishes": [{
    "id": "0",
    "name": "Uthappizza",
    "image": "images/uthappizza.png",
    "category": "mains",
    "featured": true,
    "label": "Hot",
    "price": "4.99",
    "description": "A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.",
    "comments": [{
        "rating": 5,
        "comment": "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
        "author": "John Lemon",
        "date": "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
      },
      {
        "rating": 4,
        "comment": "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
        "author": "Paul McVites",
        "date": "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
      },
      {
        "rating": 3,
        "comment": "Eat it, just eat it!",
        "author": "Michael Jaikishan",
        "date": "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
      },
      {
        "rating": 4,
        "comment": "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
        "author": "Ringo Starry",
        "date": "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
      },
      {
        "rating": 2,
        "comment": "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
        "author": "25 Cent",
        "date": "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
      },
      {
        "author": "Aayush",
        "rating": 4,
        "comment": "This is Great",
        "date": "2020-08-19T10:39:39.720Z"
      }
    ]
  }]
}
```

But when typed `localhost:3000/dishes/0`, I got

```json
{
  "id": "0",
  "name": "Uthappizza",
  "image": "images/uthappizza.png",
  "category": "mains",
  "featured": true,
  "label": "Hot",
  "price": "4.99",
  "description": "A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.",
  "comments": [
    {
      "rating": 5,
      "comment": "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
      "author": "John Lemon",
      "date": "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
    },
    {
      "rating": 4,
      "comment": "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
      "author": "Paul McVites",
      "date": "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
    },
    {
      "rating": 3,
      "comment": "Eat it, just eat it!",
      "author": "Michael Jaikishan",
      "date": "2015-02-13T17:57:28.556094Z"
    },
    {
      "rating": 4,
      "comment": "Ultimate, Reaching for the stars!",
      "author": "Ringo Starry",
      "date": "2013-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
    },
    {
      "rating": 2,
      "comment": "It's your birthday, we're gonna party!",
      "author": "25 Cent",
      "date": "2011-12-02T17:57:28.556094Z"
    },
    {
      "author": "Aayush",
      "rating": 4,
      "comment": "This is Great",
      "date": "2020-08-19T10:39:39.720Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

But now I want to get only `comments` from `dishes` of `id: "0"`. I tried `localhost:3000/dishes/0/comments` and `localhost:3000/dishes/0?comments` but did not get the desired result. What can be typed in the URL to get the table inside more tables?

Comment: You aren't showing how the backend is implemented. Based on the other end-points you've shown try `localhost:3000/dishes/0/comments/0`.

Comment: It really depends on how the backend is implemented

Comment: This is my JSON file. I need to call a particular table in my angular program. This JSON file is the backend that I am directly using.